# Why is lpSolveAPI solver slower when run the second time?

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve

The `lpSolveAPI` package in R lets you specify and solve a linear program. However calling `solve()` on an already solved LP is significantly slower than solving the LP to begin with. Why does this happen, and how can this problem be avoided?

Here is a minimal example showing the problem:

```
set.seed(42)

library(lpSolveAPI)


#------------
# Set up LP
#------------

m <- 2 ** 15

lps.model <- make.lp(nrow = m, ncol = 3)

set.column(lps.model, 1, rep(1,m))
set.column(lps.model, 2, rep(1,m))
set.column(lps.model, 3, rep(-1,m))

set.rhs(lps.model, rnorm(m) + rep(5,m))

set.objfn(lps.model,c(1,0,0))

set.constr.type(lps.model, rep(">=",m))


#-----------------
# Solve it twice
#-----------------


system.time(solve(lps.model)) # 0.02 elapsed

system.time(solve(lps.model)) # 0.14 elapsed
```

**Why does it matter?**

I am doing some sequential statistical tests; each test involves solving an LP, and each LP differs from the last in only O(log m) constraints. In theory it should be possible to do this very quickly by solving the first LP and saving the solution, editing the constraints slightly, then using the solution as a warm start for the next LP.

The problem above extends to editing the LP with `delete.constraint()` / `add.constraint()`, which makes 'efficient' solution significantly slower than the naive approach of solving each LP cold.

Comment: To get a better idea try this: `library(microbenchmark); for(i in 1:10) print(microbenchmark(lps.model, times = 10))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, microbenchmark shows pretty much the same thing. The issue is that the second time round the LP is already solved, so it doesn't make sense for it to take even as long as solving the original problem.

Comment: I got these means on successive iterations of the code in my last comment so it does not seem to increase over time for me: 1200  1170  830   960   880   1160  1070  1020  880